# [SonarLint]: make this anonymous inner class a lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, anonymous-function, sonarlint

The below code works, but I have notification from SonarLint because I use an anonymous class in stream instead of lambda expression, and I don't see how to improve the below code avoiding the notification:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
Properties temp = new Properties();
//... add some values and keys in prop and temp

prop.putAll(temp.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( entry -> !prop.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .map( new Function<Entry<Object, Object>, Entry<String, String>>(){ 
        @Override
        public Entry<String, String> apply(Entry<Object, Object> entry) {
            return new Entry<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String setValue(String value) {
                    return value.trim().toLowerCase();
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return ((String) entry.getValue()).trim().toLowerCase();
                }

                @Override
                public String getKey() {
                    return ((String) entry.getKey()).trim().toLowerCase();
                }
            };
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry<String,String>::getKey, Entry<String,String>::getValue)));
```

**Explication of code:**
I use the properties class from java.util and unfortunately, the `entrySet` of properties returns `Entry<Object, Object>`, not `Entry<String, String>`. I want to "join" the two properties objects putting key and value in lower case. So, the map allows to convert `Entry<Object, Object>` in `Entry<String,String>`. That's why, there is an anonymous class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sonar is suggesting to replace

```
prop.putAll(temp.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( entry -> !prop.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .map( new Function<Entry<Object, Object>, Entry<String, String>>(){ 
        @Override
        public Entry<String, String> apply(Entry<Object, Object> entry) {
            return new Entry<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String setValue(String value) {
                    return value.trim().toLowerCase();
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return ((String) entry.getValue()).trim().toLowerCase();
                }

                @Override
                public String getKey() {
                    return ((String) entry.getKey()).trim().toLowerCase();
                }
            };
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
```

<sup>(I removed the unnecessary type arguments in the collector)</sup>

with

```
prop.putAll(temp.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( entry -> !prop.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .map(entry -> new Entry<String, String>() { 
        @Override
        public String setValue(String value) {
            return value.trim().toLowerCase();
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return ((String) entry.getValue()).trim().toLowerCase();
        }

        @Override
        public String getKey() {
            return ((String) entry.getKey()).trim().toLowerCase();
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
```

which uses the lambda expression as replacement for the anonymous inner class implementing `Function`, not for the `Entry` implementation.

Still, it doesn’t make sense to implement the `Entry` interface manually here, especially not with the actually unwanted `setValue` method in this contract violating way. You only want an immutable `Entry` instance, therefore, you can create an instance of an existing class instead:

```
prop.putAll(temp.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( entry -> !prop.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
        ((String) entry.getKey()).trim().toLowerCase(),
        ((String) entry.getValue()).trim().toLowerCase()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
```

as a last improvement, you can get rid of the `Entry` instance entirely, when performing the transformation in the functions passed to the `toMap` collector:

```
prop.putAll(temp.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( entry -> !prop.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> ((String) entry.getKey())  .trim().toLowerCase(),
        entry -> ((String) entry.getValue()).trim().toLowerCase())));
```